# How to execute PowerShell code remotely from my Workstation ISE without install & loading module?

Tags: azure, powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory, office365

I have one dedicated server called PRODAZAD01-VM which is running Azure Active Directory Synch to Office 365.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(position = 0, mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateSet('Delta', 'Full')]
    [String]$Type,
    [string]$ComputerName = 'PRODAZAD01-VM'
)
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ArgumentList $type -ScriptBlock {
    Param($Type)
    If ($Type -eq 'Full') {$Type = 'Initial'}
    Import-Module adsync
    Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType $Type
}
```

How can I execute the PowerShell to force it to Synch from my PowerShell ISE on my laptop without installing the module & loading it every time?

Comment: You will need the module imported on the machine you are running the command from otherwise you wont have the cmdlets available.

Comment: Ok, So what the final command / script will be?

Comment: What is not working with the code you have in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Drew is pointing you to, is to use PowerShell Implicit Remoting to a machine with those cmdlet, thus proxying those cmdlets to your workstation for your session in the same way as you would with other cmdlets, say ADDS. For example -

See: [How to use AD cmdlets](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2013/06/27/how-to-use-the-2012-active-directory-powershell-cmdlets-from-windows-7)
***Update for OP ***

```
[CmdletBinding()]

Param
(
    [Parameter(position = 0, mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateSet('Delta', 'Initial')]
    [String]$Type,
    [string]$ComputerName = 'PRODAZAD01-VM',
    [string]$Creds = 'YourAdminCreds' #(Get-Credential -Credential 'YourAdminCreds')
)

$ADSession = New-PSSession -Authentication Kerberos -ComputerName $ComputerName 

Invoke-Command -Session $ADSession -ScriptBlock { 
    'ADSync','AzureADPreview','MSOnline' | 
    %{ Import-Module -Name $_ -Force } 
}

Import-PSSession -Session $ADSession
Get-Module -Name 'ADSync','AzureADPreview','MSOnline'

Connect-MsolService -Credential $Creds
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Creds

If ($Type -eq 'Delta') { Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType $Type }
Else { Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType $Type }
```

Comment: thanks for chiming in.
In your code above, how do I specify the Delta or Initial ADSync?

Comment: See my update for you. I left off the params section, because I assumed you'd add that back in. If you set a validate set, you can only use what you set. But since the cmdlet is literally expecting, Delta or Initial, why not just use them from the start.

Comment: No worries... glad it was useful

Comment: `If ($Type -eq 'Delta') { Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType $Type }
Else { Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType $Type }` - So in other words simply `Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType $Type` in both cases.

Comment: Yes, as type will contain whatever value that the user selected from the validateset option. Now, it could be simplified further by setting a default param value, thus eliminating the need for the else part of the code. Meaning run with a selection, then use the default other use the selection.

Comment: Or even value will always be one or the other, one could eliminate the if statement altogether and just do --- Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType $Type --- That is if there is no other things you need to do in that if statement.

Comment: Yeah, the unneeded if was what I was getting at.